# Visual Studio - Xamarin Forms, increment apk, app version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I have an apk(v 1.0.2) developed in visual studio with xamarin forms and I need delivery news features in another version (1.0.2). 
Whats is the steps to delivery the newer version ? Just change the version in android project options and generate an new archive with the same signature key ??
What’s the inputs to change in android project options ?
Thanks

Comment: Right click on Android project -> Properties and from Android Manifest UI change `version number` and `version name` and upload the new .apk to the store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your .Droid project in your solution explorer, click on properties.

Click on Android Manifest. From there you can change your app version name and increment the version number.

After that, generate a new archive the same way you did previously.